# Bottom actionbar with shared animation

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-bottomappbar

How can we implement the bottom action bar in link( 
https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#behavior ) with shared animation of fab across activity  [image: Like this one]